# SQL Query Excel - return "0" if value not found

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, null, return-value

I have a simple query that uses the following command text to return values from a SQL Server to an Excel sheet. However, when the `Material` value is not found in the `Material_Location` table, it simply omits it.

How can I modify the following code to return the value of `On_Hand_Qty` as "0", if the `Material` is not found in the `Material_Location` table

```
    SELECT
      SO_Detail.Sales_Order,
      SO_Detail.SO_Line,
      SO_Detail.Material,
      SO_Detail.Order_Qty,
      Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty
     FROM
      SO_Detail
      INNER JOIN Material_Location ON SO_Detail.Material = Material_Location.Material
    ORDER BY
      SO_Detail.Sales_Order,
      SO_Detail.SO_Line
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `ifnull(Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty,0)`

Comment: There is a lot of ways to do it, using `CASE`, `ISNULL`, `IIF`, `COALESCE`

Comment: @Sami - before that we need `Left Outer Join` to get the non matching record

Comment: Use a `left join`

Comment: @Pரதீப் Yeah, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `left outer join` instead of `inner join` will allow you to still get records from `SO_Detail` even when no matching record exists in `Material_Location`.

`COALESCE` will go through each parameter passed to it until it finds one that is not null

```
SELECT
  sd.Sales_Order,
  sd.SO_Line,
  sd.Material,
  sd.Order_Qty,
  COALESCE(ml.On_Hand_Qty,0) as On_Hand_Qty
 FROM
  SO_Detail sd
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Material_Location ml ON sd.Material = ml.Material
ORDER BY
  sd.Sales_Order,
  sd.SO_Line
```

Comment: @Pரதீப் not sure what you mean?

Comment: @gordatron - Query looks lot better now :) +1

Comment: @Pரதீப் i was wondering if that was what you meant :D all those characters just too much for you? if i had not copied and pasted i would not have been able to bring myself to type that all out XD